# ¿Cómo generar un gráfico de líneas en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

tengo esta función en C# que genera un gráfico de barras con información de una base de datos en visual studio.

```
    public ActionResult GraficoBarras()
    {
        var chart = new Chart();
        var area = new ChartArea();
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
        var series = new Series();
        foreach (var item in usuarios)
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(item.NombreUsuario, item.Contador);
        }
        series.Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        series["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
        chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
        chart.SaveImage(returnStream);
        returnStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(returnStream, "image/png");
    }
```

Lo que quiero es convertirlo en un gráfico de líneas, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Alguno de ustedes sabe qué debo modificar para que se muestre como un gráfico de líneas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
```

solo debes cambiar:

```
 series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

si deseas probar otros tipos :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype?view=netframework-4.8